# Difference between 2 dependent Erlang variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Suppose we have two Erlang random variables X and Y that are dependent.
X ~ Erlang(1, k) and Y ~ Erlang(3, k).
Let Z = Y - X.
Would the moment generating function of Z be equivalent to the moment generating function of Y divided by that of X and hence Z ~ Erlang(2, k)?